# Glassfish RAR5035:Unexpected Exception While Destroying Resource From Pool

Tags: jdbc, glassfish, ejb, connection-pooling, ejb-3.1

I have a Java EE web application. I am connecting database with JDBC and I am using JDBC connection pool. My application's main page is login page. After I enter the login page and wait for a while, I take this glassfish server(4.1.0) warning consistently.

> Warning:   RAR5035:Unexpected exception while destroying resource from
>   pool OraclePool. Exception message: Error while destroying resource
>   :IO Error: Socket read timed out

Even if I don't do any action on the page. When I monitore the statistics of the connection pool, `NumConnCreated` is increasing continuously. How can I solve the problem?. Thank you.

[image: pool_statistics_image]

This is my managed bean class.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Login implements Serializable{

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private User user;
    private @EJB DBRemote db;

public void test(){
        String[] params1 = {"user","1234"};
        int[] getParams = {Types.INTEGER,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR};
        CallableStatement statement = db.run("TBL.USERLOGIN(?,?,?,?,?,?)", params1 , getParams);

        try {
           int isLogin = statement.getInt(3);
           if (isLogin==1) {
               String uName = statement.getString(4);
               String uId = statement.getString(5);
               user = new User(uId, uName, isLogin);
               System.out.println("LOGGED IN " + uName + "\t" + uId);
           }else{
               String errMessage = statement.getString(6);
               user = new User(errMessage,isLogin);
               System.out.println("LOG IN FAILURE " + errMessage);
           }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            db.close();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("infoback", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "TEST","Test Works"));
        }
    }

}
```

This my interface class

```
@Remote
public interface DBRemote {
    CallableStatement run(String query, String[] setParams, int[] getParams);
    void close();
    String getErrorMessage();
    String getSql();
}
```

This is my Stateless Bean class

```
@Stateless
public class DB implements DBRemote{

    @Resource(mappedName = "pwresource")
    private DataSource ds;

    private String sql;
    private String errorMessage;
    private CallableStatement statement;
    private Connection connection;

    public DB() {
    }

    @Override
    public CallableStatement run(String query, String[] setParams, int[] getParams){
        sql = "{call " + query + "}";
        int getParamIndex = setParams.length + 1;
        try {
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
            for (int i = 0; i < setParams.length; i++) {
                statement.setString(i+1, setParams[i]);
            }
            for (int getParam : getParams) {
                statement.registerOutParameter(getParamIndex, getParam);
                getParamIndex++;
            }
           statement.execute();

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (ex.getErrorCode()==17008) {
                errorMessage = "Timeout";
            }else{
                errorMessage = "System Error";
            }
            Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            close();
        }
        return statement;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(){
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if(connection != null){
                connection.close();
            }
        errorMessage = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            errorMessage = "Close Connection Error";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. My problem is because of the connection between connection pool and database. Database closes the connections automically because of the server and database in different networks caused timeout issue.

Comment: Even for me has same issue. How you solved this issue? Please give us some steps to solve.

Comment: The problem can be in your connection pool or in database, no relevance with Java side. For me, it was a database configuration issue that database was blocking the connection because of that the server was in the different network. @Raj